# Fedora 23 java --version command returns warning message Illegal option: -

Tags: java, linux, fedora-23

Please refer the following screenshot, when I request for `java --version` it shows up a warning message `Illegal option: -`

```
    [root@localhost usr]# java -version
Usage: jar {ctxui}[vfmn0PMe] [jar-file] [manifest-file] [entry-point] [-C dir] files ...
Options:
    -c  create new archive
    -t  list table of contents for archive
    -x  extract named (or all) files from archive
    -u  update existing archive
    -v  generate verbose output on standard output
    -f  specify archive file name
    -m  include manifest information from specified manifest file
    -n  perform Pack200 normalization after creating a new archive
    -e  specify application entry point for stand-alone application 
        bundled into an executable jar file
    -0  store only; use no ZIP compression
    -P  preserve leading '/' (absolute path) and ".." (parent directory) components from file names
    -M  do not create a manifest file for the entries
    -i  generate index information for the specified jar files
    -C  change to the specified directory and include the following file
If any file is a directory then it is processed recursively.
The manifest file name, the archive file name and the entry point name are
specified in the same order as the 'm', 'f' and 'e' flags.

Example 1: to archive two class files into an archive called classes.jar: 
       jar cvf classes.jar Foo.class Bar.class 
Example 2: use an existing manifest file 'mymanifest' and archive all the
           files in the foo/ directory into 'classes.jar': 
       jar cvfm classes.jar mymanifest -C foo/ .
```

Please explain how to debug and resolve this.

Thanks

Comment: it's `java -version` with only one `-`...

Comment: I tried that too but the result is same, I am new to fedora, I installed a bunch of softwares including eclipse, mysql etc., Last time all is well but after restart /usr/bin/java not found, what could be potential cause?

Comment: It's weird: the output is that of the`jar` command - you seem to have linked `java` to the wrong command... (Also it would be better to copy paste the output in the question as text instead of an image).

Comment: I have used the instructions given in the following link to install java
http://www.tecmint.com/install-java-jdk-jre-in-linux/ , The problem is with step 7

Comment: The output of step 7 mentioned in http://www.tecmint.com/install-java-jdk-jre-in-linux/

`[root@localhost jdk1.8.0_77]# update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/ja
jackd    jackrec  java     javac    
[root@localhost jdk1.8.0_77]# update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/jar jar /opt/jdk1.8.0_77/bin/jar 100
the primary link for jar must be /usr/bin/java
`

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with the `JRE_HOME`, wrong path has been set. Once the following command has been executed, the problem is resolved.

```
 export JRE_HOME=/opt/java/jdk1.8.0._45/jre
```

In my case I have reinstalled `java` to resolve the issue.